# Select into Temp table cannot exist in seperate IF condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempTable2;

IF @someCondition is not null
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #tempTable2 FROM Table; --No problem, no error
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #tempTable2 FROM Table; --Execution failed
END
```

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 197 There is already an object named
>   '#tempTable2' in the database.

May I know what could be the reason for the above case? Procedurally, the query in first IF section was not being executed and hence it should not create #tempTable2

Comment: You can add the `drop table` to the else part. As to why this happens I'm not sure. Perhaps the creation of the table is done when SQL Server parses your statement, **Before** it's executed, and thus is unaware of the result of the condition beforehand.

Comment: I've tested to put the `drop table` command in both `IF` section but it's not working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two statements in the same procedure that create a temp table with the same name. 
This is a leftover from SQL 6.5 which did not have deferred name resolution.

Instead of using `select into`, use `create table + insert`.

[Answer by Erland Sommarskog on MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7ddea5-1021-429c-bdb2-c3a4df245320/why-am-i-getting-there-is-already-an-object-named-temptable-in-the-database-within-my-sql?forum=transactsql)

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable2') is not null
  drop table #tempTable2;

create table #tempTable2 (...);

if @someCondition is not null
begin
  insert into #tempTable2 
  select * from Table;
end
else
begin
    insert into #tempTable2 
    select * from Table;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can understand my pour english.
the problem  is not "if" but the statement of "select"
with the structure "select * into table2 from table1"will create the ssms a new table automatically.
that means,when you use the same statement in another time,the table2 has already created in your database.
you don't need to create it again or you can create it with another name.